# How can avoid to create a new ol element every time (Table of Contents) js

Tags: javascript, tableofcontents

I dont know how to avoid this. I want the result of this, but not to generate a new ol elemnt every time. Thanks to that the numeration is wrong.

```js
function myFunction() { 
           
            var toc = document.getElementById('continguts');
            var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4');
            var tabla = document.createElement('ol');

            for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
                if (headings[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h1') {
                    posi = document.createElement('li');
                    var content = document.createTextNode(headings[i].textContent);
                    posi.appendChild(content);
                    tabla.appendChild(posi);
                }
                if (headings[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h2') {
                    tabla2 = document.createElement('ol');
                    posi2 = document.createElement('li');
                    var content = document.createTextNode(headings[i].textContent);
                    posi2.appendChild(content);
                    tabla2.appendChild(posi2);
                    posi.appendChild(tabla2);
                    tabla.appendChild(posi);
                }
                if (headings[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h3') {
                    posi3 = document.createElement('li');
                    tabla3 = document.createElement('ol');
                    var content = document.createTextNode(headings[i].textContent);
                    posi3.appendChild(content);
                    tabla3.appendChild(posi3);
                    posi2.appendChild(tabla3);
                    tabla2.appendChild(posi2);
                    posi.appendChild(tabla2);
                    tabla.appendChild(posi);
                }                  
            }
            toc.appendChild(tabla);
        }
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <p id="continguts"></p>
  <h1>Apartat 1.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum .</p>
  <h2>Apartat 1.2.</h2>
  <p>Nunc blandit, nulla</p>
  <p>Proin posuere </p>
  <h3>Apartat 1.2.1.</h3>
  <p>Etiam justo </p>
  <h2>Apartat 1.3.</h2>
  <p> Lorem </p>
  <p>Nunc blandit, </p>
  <h3>Apartat 1.3.1.</h3>
  <p> rhoncus sed, </p>
  <h4>Apartat 1.3.1.1.</h4>
  <p>Praesent non quam id felis luctus sodales.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Tough to help without seeing your html, but if your `tabla` is the only thing inside of `toc`, try `toc.innerHTML = '';` before that for loop.

Comment: `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Exercici 3.1.5. - DOM b&agrave;sic</title>  
</head> 
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <p id="continguts"></p>  
    <h1>Apartat 1.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum .</p>
    <h2>Apartat 1.2.</h2>
    <p>Nunc blandit, nulla</p>
    <p>Proin posuere  </p>
    <h3>Apartat 1.2.1.</h3>
    <p>Etiam justo </p>
    <h2>Apartat 1.3.</h2>
    <p> Lorem </p>
    <p>Nunc blandit,  </p>
    <h3>Apartat 1.3.1.</h3>
    <p> rhoncus sed, </p>
    <h4>Apartat 1.3.1.1.</h4>
    <p>Praesent non quam id felis luctus sodales.</p>
</body>
</html>`